# SPRING MVC : Getting key value returned from form:select

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring MVC in class and have been wondering why my form select sends the key of my map instead of the value selected.

Here's the display:

**Form inputs -**

[image: form inputs]

**Displaying result -**

[image: displaying result]

Here's my code :

Controller :

```
package com.mycompany.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import entity.User;

@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    
    @Value("#{countries}")
    private Map<String, String> listCountry;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome()
    {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("needForm")
    public String displayForm(Model model)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : listCountry.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("countries", listCountry);
        return "userForm";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("processForm")
    public String filledForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
    {
        System.out.println(user.getCountry());
        return "viewForm";
    }

}
```

Entity :

```
package entity;

public class User {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private int age;
        
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String pays) {
        this.country = pays;
    }
    
}
```

countries.properties file

```
FR = France
IT = Italie
ES = Espagne
RU = Russie
BE = Belgique
```

First JSP sending param (userForm) :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" 
uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>user form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="user">
        First Name :    <form:input path="firstName" /> <br><br>
        Last Name :     <form:input path="lastName" /> <br><br>
        Age :           <form:input path="age" /> <br><br>
        Pays :
        <form:select path="country">
            <form:options items="${countries}"/>
        </form:select>
        <input type="submit" value="valider"/>
    </form:form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Second JSP getting param (viewForm) :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>viewForm</title>
</head>
<body>
User:<br>
<br>
First name : ${user.firstName}<br>
<br>
Last name : ${user.lastName}<br>
<br>
Age : ${user.age}<br>
<br>
pays: ${user.country}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because that is how it works. The key is used as the value for the input, while the value with that key is used as the description/text.

Comment: So If i want it plain text, I should change the text of the key, to match that of the value i guess. Thank you (wonder if I could change it though)